# i want to send mail to forget password in django

Tags: python, django

my views.py

```
def ForgetPassword(request):
try:
    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')

        if not User.objects.filter(username=username).first():
            messages.success(request,'not user found with this username')
            return redirect('forget-password/')
        
        user_obj=User.objects.get(username=username)
        token=str(uuid.uuid4())
        send_forget_password_mail(user_obj,token)
        messages.success(request,'An email is sent')
        return redirect('/forget-password/')
    

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
return render(request,'forget-password.html')
```

helpers.py

```
def send_forget_password_mail(email, token):
subject="your forget password link"
message=f'hi, click on the link to rest your password http://127.0.0.1:8000/change-password/{token}/'
email_from=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
recipient_list=[email]
send_mail(subject,message, email_from, recipient_list)
return True
```

i have created a function which will send mail if anyone click on forget password but email is not sending.

Comment: any errors you get?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are giving the helper function a user object when what it requires is the user email. So you can modify your code as below:

```py
def forget_password(request):
    try:
        if request.method=="POST":
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            user_obj = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()

            if user_obj is None:
                messages.error(request,'not user found with this username')
                return redirect('forget-password/')

            token=str(uuid.uuid4())
            send_forget_password_mail(user_obj.email, token)
            messages.success(request,'An email is sent')
            return redirect('/forget-password/')
        

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return render(request,'forget-password.html')
```

Note that, in Python, we tend to name functions in lowercase separated by underscores, i.e snake_case.

Comment: I tried your code but still it's nit running

Comment: the error showing is "Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e12-20020a170902744c00b001b8a2edab6asm572250plt.244 - gsmtp')"